# Is there grunt tasks for generating images sprites according by css?

Tags: css, sprite, gruntjs

Let's say I have the following style.css file:

```
h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background: url('/img/header.png');
}
p {
   background: url('/img/p.png');
}
```

I need to make image sprite for this css automatically. I need to get something like this:

```
h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background: url('/img/sprite.png') -47px 0;
}
p {
   background: url('/img/sprite.png') -130px 0;
}
```

Is it possible to make automaticaly by using grunt task?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are looking for this [grunt-sprite-generator](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-sprite-generator). From the documentation:

> Grunt task that generates a sprite from images referenced in a stylesheet and then updates the references with the new sprite image and positions

Another tool that looks to fit the bill is [grunt-spritesmith](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-spritesmith)

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Grunt Imagine](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-imagine)?